# Python-sys.argv code for finding number of upper case letters in a string

Tags: python, string, command-line, count

I wrote a code below in sys.argv library in Python to find the number of upper case letters. This code returns `None` in input - *ApplE is HoT*. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
def c_upper(s):
    upper = 0
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper():
            upper += 1
        else:
            pass

s = str(sys.argv[1])
print(c_upper(s))

c_upper(s)
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
# foo.py
import sys
def c_upper(s):
    upper = 0
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper():
            upper += 1
    return upper

print(c_upper(sys.argv[1]))
```

Run:

```
python3 foo.py 'ApplE is HoT' # 4
```

1. Your function is not returning anything, so the function implicitly returns `None`. That's why you are seeing `None`. You need to use `return upper` to return the value; note that return statement is *outside* the `for` loop.
2. `else: pass` is redundant.
3. `sys.argv[1]` is already a string, so `str` in front of `sys.argv[1]` is redundant.
4. Once you learn list- or generator- comprehension, you will see the following will be an easier option:

   ```py
   def c_upper(s):
       return sum(c.isupper() for c in s)
   ```

Comment: Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable s is unable to retrieve the text so correct it.

```html
import sys
def c_upper(s):
    upper = 0
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper():
            upper += 1
        else:
            pass
    return upper
s = 'ApplE is HoT'
print(c_upper(s))

c_upper(s)
print(s)
```